# Java Card game server, can't figure out how to start from beginning without havng a goto

Tags: java, tcp

I dont know how to do this without using a goto.

I'm making a network card reading game that has .. states, waiting for at least 2 players   After 2 players have entered it does a while loop, where after game is finshed it will repeat.  Within this loop, there are 3 more loops for shuffle, turn card over look at card.  If in any of the 3 loops, players quit and there is only 1 or no players left, how can I make it go to the top of the code where the waiting for 2 player loop is

```
Do{
// waiting for two player???
….......
} while less then 2 players
while(true)
{
   shuffle cards
   wait for all players to see cards

    ****** if players quit how can it go to waiting state

    do{
        turn card over
        ****** if players quit how can it go to waiting state
        wait for all players to see card
        Look at the card blown up
          } while turn over cards<12)
} // true reloop game
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for labels.  If you have nested loops, you can `continue` the outer loop if it has a label:

```
outer:
while(x){
   // ...

   while(y){

      // someone quit
      continue outer;

   }

   // ...
}
```

By wrapping your whole code in a while loop, when you need to "quit", just continue the outer loop to start back from the start.

Comment: You may want to mention `break outer;` too. Also, I like to name the label meaningfully, especially so the `continue` reads nicely, eg `continue waitingForTwoPlayers`

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping all of those loops around in another `while(true)`. That way when the game loop exits, it goes back to the beginning and waits for more players, then continues to play the game again.